# Configure ASP.NET Core App to set new default files

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I went thru the documentation provided for [Use Static Files](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html) for ASP.NET core app. After Reading information from section [Serving a default document](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html#serving-a-default-document) & [Using the UseFileServer method](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html#using-the-usefileserver-method), following two questions are opened in my mind, respectively:

1. How can I add new default file if it is outside of wwwroot
2. How can I add new default file which is even under www using UseFileServer extension method

Answer (score 0):

In your Startup.Configure method you can configure the default file:

```
DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
options.DefaultFileNames.Add("myDefault.html"); // this had no influence :-(
app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
```

If I define the following options, I can load the default `index.html` through `/StaticFiles` but not my customized `myDefault.html` which is probably what you are after.

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:\temp\"),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles"),
    EnableDefaultFiles = true,
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
});
```

`UseDefaultFiles` doesn't seem to have any influence. However it should still work if you configure the default file in your web server.
`FileServerOptions` has a property `DefaultFiles`, but it is read-only.

Comment: Actually my question is little further than what you mentioned. I do not want to change root location, however  **1** I want to add more default files from outside wwwroot. So I want combination of whichever present as default under wwwroot along with outsider.  **2**, achieve adding new default files even from wwwroot using `app.UseFileServer` extension method.

Comment: I thought so. I tried the same but couldn't get it to work, except with the default page which was configured in IIS (index.html). It might be dependent on the web server whether UseDefaultFiles works with a new default filename or not.